# Is it better to combine or leave alone 2D polygons

Tags: 2d, box2d, physics-engine

I'm making a modular system for a 2D spaceship arcade like game, the user builds their own ship with equilateral triangles to make more complex shapes. When the ships are small it's no problem, but as you make bigger ships you would have to add more bodies to the physics engine, so I think I should just combine all the bodies and make a polygon outlining the shape I'm making and simply render it as multiple. But I've also heard it's really computationally expensive to use shapes other than squares, triangles, and circles.

Tldr: I have a compound of triangles, should I just leave it as is? Or make a polygon outlining the overall shape? Which is better performing? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Do you need to be able to blow the ship apart?   (Also, I'm curious - are you _really_ using equilateral triangles, or perhaps right triangles?  It's harder to handle equilateral ones, but could lead to some interesting configurations!)

Comment: How many ships of this style are to be checked each frame?

Comment: Have you tried building a ship-sized object out of simple primitive shapes, and out of larger polygons, and profiling both cases to compare their performance? This looks like a question you can answer for your own specific needs through your own testing.

Comment: @AC yeah, that's the idea, and yeah I'm using all equilateral triangles

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt less than 4. with an average of 30 equilateral triangles per ship

Comment: @DMGregory I mean, I have no idea how to even begin to do that XD to be honest I only started recently

Comment: Well, then I've done a VERY similar thing with a ship comprised of parts that came from a square grid, but which had polygonal physics shapes since the parts may not have completely filled their squares (there were connectivity rules that prevented nonsensical arrangements). It's anecdotal, but I didn't have any performance troubles on commodity hardware a couple of years ago with a *single* ship plus a similarly-constructed "target" (plus an Earth, for bonus orbital mechanics). IIRC the ship was at most 30 or 42 such physics bodies, but that was not a performance limitation (it was aesthetic)